# Replace numbers within a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I currently have this code.

```
var result = {
    productName: $(".product-details .product-title").text().trim(),
    description: $(".product-details .product-description p").text().trim(),
    price: $(".product-details .price-lockup meta[itemprop='lowPrice']").attr("content"),
    imageUrls: []
};

$('.image-cache img[src*="?fit=fill&bg=fff&fm=jpg&q=60&w=380&h=583"]').each( function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("src");
    result.imageUrls.push(url);
});
```

What I'm wanting to do is replace '380' and '583' within the src string with 860 and 1318. I've read a few questions here but they don't actually deal with finding and replacing them with other numbers.

Any help would be brilliant!

Comment: you can do a simple replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var url = $(this).attr("src").replace("380","860").replace("583","1318");
```

---

Complete function:

```
var result = {
    productName: $(".product-details .product-title").text().trim(),
    description: $(".product-details .product-description p").text().trim(),
    price: $(".product-details .price-lockup meta[itemprop='lowPrice']").attr("content"),
    imageUrls: []
};

$('.image-cache img[src*="?fit=fill&bg=fff&fm=jpg&q=60&w=380&h=583"]').each( function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("src").replace("380","860").replace("583","1318");
    result.imageUrls.push(url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the String [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```
url = url.replace('380', '860');
url = url.replace('583', '1318');
```

Comment: How would this fit within the function?

Comment: Also you can chain those replace functions like this: `url=url.replace(''380,'860').replace('583','1318');`